# create a sitting arrangement using javascript(node.js)

Tags: javascript

I have given a row of seats. Each seat is either occupied by a woman (denoted by xx) or a man (denoted by xy).

The objective is to find the minimum number of seat exchanges required such that the men and women are seated alternately.

**Input Format**

The first line of input consists of an integer `t` denoting the number of test cases. `t` test cases follow. Each test case consists of two lines. The first line of each test case consists of an integer n denoting the number of seats. Second line consists of n space separated tokens, each token denoting the occupant of that particular seat.

**Output Format**

For each test case, print the number of seat exchanges required. If an alternate seating is impossible, print -1.

**Sample Input**

```
5
3
xx xx xx
2
xx xy
4
xx xx xy xy
8
xx xx xy xy xy xx xx xy
7
xx xy xx xy xx xy xy
```

**Sample Output**

```
-1
0
1
2
3
```

Constraints
1 <= t <= 1000

1 <= n <= 10000

**Explanation**
For xx xx xy xy, one can exchange seat 1 with seat 4 giving xy xx xy xx giving an alternate seating arrangement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Assignments aren't usually arbitrary; your instructor, tutorial, or course will have covered the necessary topics to make it possible for you to do this. **Review your course materials, class notes, etc.,** and give it a try. *If* you run into a *specific* problem, research it thoroughly, [search thoroughly here](/help/searching), and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. People will be glad to help.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hey I have explained my  question very well, I just want to get some idea how to do it.

Comment: Please, again, read the [help]. This is far too broad for SO's format. Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Reads like you are giving some kind of coding challenge. SO is the kind of place where if you would get stuck trying to code this yourself, you'd show your code and ask for help on a specific issue you are having.

Comment: I agree with @T.J. Crowder though you might want to look into [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) guess I'm new and still have pity

Comment: @T.J.Crowder still if you can help me out, it would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I just thought this was really fun, so I attempted to do the main algorithm, the implementation details, I'll leave them to you

```js
function minimumswitches(seats) {
  //men are 1, women are 0
  var l = seats.length;
  //Let's count men and women!
  var m = seats.filter(a => a == 1).length;
  var w = seats.filter(a => a == 0).length;
  /*when is a seating impossible?
  for example in 1 seat, 1 man and 1 woman would be valid
  for 2 seats, 2 men, 2 women is invalid
  for 3 seats, 3 people of the same gender would be invalid
  for 4 seats, 3 people of the same gender would be invalid
  for 5 seats, 4 people of the same gender is invalid
  Basically ceil the half of a number add 1 and it is invalid except for 1
  **/
  if (l !== 1 && ((Math.ceil(l / 2) + 1) <= m) || ((Math.ceil(l / 2) + 1) <= w)) {
    return -1;
  }
  //if l is even then there should be the same amount of women as men
  //if l is odd, then the beginning should start with whatever is most  
  //ok so the plan is to get the "right order" see how many are wrong, and count them and split by 2, it sounds as a nice strategy.
  if (l % 2 == 0) {
    //if l is even
    var wrong1 = 0;
    //start with men
    seats.forEach((b, i) => {
      if (b === (i + 1) % 2) wrong1++;
    });
    //start with women
    var wrong2 = 0;
    seats.forEach((b, i) => {
      if (b === (i) % 2) wrong2++;
    });
    //return the less wrong answer lol
    return Math.min(wrong1, wrong2) / 2;
  }
  if (l % 2 == 1) {
    //if l is odd
    var wrong = 0;
    var startsWithWomen = +(m > w);
    seats.forEach((b, i) => {
      if (b !== (i + startsWithWomen) % 2) wrong++;
    });
    return wrong / 2;
  }
  //this should never return floating point
}

//This is how to use it
console.log(minimumswitches([0,0,1,1]));
console.log(minimumswitches([0,1,0,1,0,1,1]));
```